# How to run PySpark Job in AWS Glue Python Shell Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have small data sets and I want to run a PySpark Job in AWS Glue Python Shell Job to reduce the cost. Is there any way to run the PySpark Job in AWS Glue Python Shell Job?

Answer (score 0):

To run a PySpark job you need a Spark infrastructure (a cluster with multiple nodes splitting your data and coordinating themselves to process your data in parallel).

When you opt for a Python shell job you get a single process running on a single node a Python script. If you don't have a lot of data to process this is indeed a cheaper option however you won't have access to the Spark APIs (ex. DataFrame). Have a look at Pandas module, you get APIs close enough to Spark.

Comment: I want to write the data to the Athena Iceberg tabe.  Spark API has integration with Iceberg format which is difficult to achieve in Pandas Datafarame. Due to this reason I want to use Spark in Python Shell Job.

Since the Python shell runs on a single node, Spark Standalone mode (single node) can be used in this.

Comment: Installing PySpark and Spark each time you launch you job might be possible though I suspect it will be complex to tune. This [article](https://www.dremio.com/blog/3-ways-to-use-python-with-apache-iceberg/) mentions pyiceberg as an alternative to create iceberg tables.

Comment: You can also use Athena CTAS queries to create an Iceberg table, check this [article](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/039%20-%20Athena%20Iceberg.html).